# R - Construct a string with double quotations

Tags: r, string

I basically need the outcome (string) to have double quotations, thus need of escape character. Preferabily solving with R base, without extra R packages.

I have tried with squote, shQuote and noquote. They just manipulate the quotations, not the escape character.

My list:

```
power <- "test"

myList <- list (
                "power" = power)
```

I subset the content using:

```
myList
myList$power
```

**Expected outcome (a string with following content):**

`" \"power\": \"test\" "`

Comment: The expected output is a little bit unclear."Without the [\"]" isn't clear. Do you just want to add ":"?

Comment: @NelsonGo Added some spaces in the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `shQuote`

```
paste(shQuote(names(myList), type = "cmd"),
      shQuote(unlist(myList), type = "cmd"),
      sep = ": ")
# [1] "\"power\": \"test\""
```

Answer (score 3):

Using package `glue`:

```
library(glue)
glue(' "{names(myList)}": "{myList}" ')
 "power": "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to get your expectation. Is it what you want?

```
myList <- list (
  "power" = "test"
)
stringr::str_remove_all(
  as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(myList, auto_unbox = TRUE)), 
  "[\\{|\\}]")
# [1] "\"power\":\"test\""
```

If you want some spaces:

```
x <- stringr::str_remove_all(
  as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(myList, auto_unbox = TRUE)), 
  "[\\{|\\}]")
paste0(" ", x, " ")
```